# Need to fire a function on number change automatically if no more changes were made to number input for sometime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs (input[number])[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D]. In this I need to triger an action automatically after a few seconds only if no more number changes were made during these few seconds, say 2 seconds.

In my [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/bLzqGbu6QdbD6vokJguZ?p=preview), the action is called everytime the number changes, but instead I need the action to be fired only when user has not changed any value for more than 2 seconds.

```
<div class="col-md-3 divGridText">
    <label for="excludeMinutesStep" style="font-weight:bold">Exclude tasks &lt; </label>
    <input id="excludeMinutesStep" min="0" max="10" ng-model="excludeValue" ng-change="numericStepperChanged(excludeValue)" size="2" style="width:40px;" type="number" /> <b>minutes</b>
</div>

$scope.excludeValue = 5;
$scope.numericStepperInitValue = 0;

$scope.numericStepperChanged = function(data) {console.log("A");
  $scope.numericStepperHit = true;
  if (data != undefined) {
    $scope.excludeValue = data;
    if (data == 0) {
      $scope.isExcludeNeeded = false;
    }

    if ($scope.numericStepperInitValue == 0) {
      $timeout($scope.callAtNumercStepperChangeTimeout, 2000);
    }
  }
}

$scope.callAtNumercStepperChangeTimeout = function() {
  $scope.numericStepperHit = false;
  $scope.numericStepperInitValue++;
  $scope.changeGraph();
}

$scope.changeGraph = function() {
  if (!$scope.numericStepperHit) {
    console.log("Action called "+$scope.excludeValue);
    $scope.mytext = "Action called "+$scope.excludeValue;
    $scope.isExcludeNeeded = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called debouncing and it is a very well-known pattern.

You can use undercoreJs debounce:

```
$scope.debouncedFunction = _.debounce(myFunction, 2000);

<input ng-change="debouncedFunction()" size="2" style="width:40px;" type="number" />
```

Or you can implement it yourself. Something like this:

```
var promise = null;
function debouncedFcn{
    if(promise)
        $timeout.cancel(promise);
    var promise = $timeout(myFunction, 2000);
}
```

Reference: [Debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

Comment: Is there an angularjs way of doing this?

Comment: But please note that both solutions I presented are Angular-friendly and angular doesn't offer built-in debounce utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I made a function named timer that checks if value changed in 2 sec.İf not fires mainFunction() that fires an alert. And used timer function in $scope.$watch , that watches excludeValue change

```
$scope.excludeValue = 5;

 $scope.$watch('excludeValue',function(oldVal,newVal){
   if(oldVal !== newVal) // a new change 
   {
      timer(oldVal,newVal)
   }
 });

 var timer = function(oldVal,newVal){
   var currentVal = angular.copy($scope.excludeValue);
   $timeout(function(){
     if(currentVal == $scope.excludeValue)
     {
       // there is no change made in 2 sec 
       mainFunction()
     }
     else
     {
       // change made in 2 sec
     }
   }, 2000);
 };

 timer();

 var mainFunction = function(){
   alert('No change made in 2 sec.');
 };
```

here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aSiWIjprNV3WeqVjANoY?p=preview)

Comment: What is the need for `oldVal` & `newVal` in timer function?

Comment: I thought you want to keep old value dont changed unless any change made in 2 sec .İf there is no change made in 2 sec.you can set value to oldVal. But in your question i guess you dont need that